# PHP division resulting in NaN - maybe related to DateTime functions

Tags: php, datetime, date, nan, datediff

I'm currently trying to do a "time ago" function but for some reason, it ends up giving me a NaN for one of the results.

I'm using a slightly modified version of this piece of code (found at: http://www.sitepoint.com/create-your-own-twitter-widget-3/ )

```
    if ($this->DateFormat == 'friendly') {
        // friendly date format
        $ival = $now->diff($stime);
        $yr = $ival->y;
        $mh = $ival->m + ($ival->d > 15);
        if ($mh > 11) $yr = 1;
        $dy = $ival->d + ($ival->h > 15);
        $hr = $ival->h;
        $mn = $ival->i + ($ival->s > 29);
        if ($yr > 0) {
            if ($yr == 1) $date = 'last year';
            else $date = $yr . ' years ago';
        }
        else if ($mh > 0) {
            if ($mh == 1) $date = 'last month';
            else $date = $mh . ' months ago';
        }
        else if ($dy > 0) {
            if ($dy == 1) $date = 'yesterday';
            else if ($dy < 8) $date = $dy . ' days ago';
            else if ($dy < 15) $date = 'last week';
            else $date = round($dy / 7) . ' weeks ago';
        }
        else if ($hr > 0) {
            $hr += ($ival->i > 29);
            $date = $hr . ' hour' . ($hr == 1 ? '' : 's') . ' ago';
        }
        else {
            if ($mn < 3) $date = 'just now';
            else $date = $mn . ' minutes ago';
        }
    }
```

(the problematic line is the one with the `round($dy / 7)`

I created a set of possible values to test the outcomes and it gives me a NaN for a date of -29 days. The thing is that it only happens to do that when I repeat the function over and over. If I just test -29 days alone, it outputs me the correct 4 weeks value.

Any idea on how can I avoid/fix this?

**Edit**

This is most likely a bug in PHP.

If I make the code do the division and rounding twice, the NaN never appears.

```
// do estimate of how many weeks ago
$round = round($days / 7, 0);
$round = round($days / 7, 0);

$date =  $round . ' weeks ago';
```

I noticed this because in my test loops, the first value that triggered the weeks calculation (given that I was making more than one calculation) would give the NaN.

Comment: `$dy = $ival->d + ($ival->h > 15);` - since when did we start having 30-odd hours in a day? :-) I think that `15` should be `11`.

Comment: I could be mistaken but isn't it just rounding 1 day and 16 hours to 2 days for example?

Comment: Yes, but it's the `15` value I'm disputing. Half a day is 12 hours, not 16. The other two calculation are 15 (for 32-ish days) and 29 (for 60 seconds). This looks like a clear cut'n'paste problem from the previous calculation. Not that this will fix your problem, hence a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: `This is most likely a bug in PHP.` -- You should have very strong proof before raising such claims. Finding bugs in such basic operations in a widely used language is... unlikely. :)

Comment: Definitely a bug. Dealing with this now. PHP 5.3.3 thread safe version on Windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I personally believe this was bug (I found some bug submissions and stackoverflow questions having similar problems) it doesnt seem to be happening anymore after going from 5.3.1 to 5.3.5.

This is a simplified code that would give NaN for me

```
// create datetimes
$date1 = new Datetime();
$date2 = new Datetime();

/* loop part - taken out for simplicity */

$date1->diff($date2);
echo 1 . "<br/>";
// 1

$date1->diff($date2);
echo 2 . "<br/>";
// 2

$date1->diff($date2);
echo round((29 / 7)) . "<br/>";
// NAN

$date1->diff($date2);
echo round((29 / 7)) . '<br/>';
// 4
```

(I was running XAMPP 1.7.3 (PHP 5.3.1) on Windows)

Comment: This is definitely a bug. Dealing with it now and also found bug #52920 on php.net. This is a frustrating bug. I'm getting it on PHP 5.3.3 thread safe version on windows.

Answer (score 2):

interestingly my hack had worked on similar problem. I just put this before the operations with the date:

```
if (is_nan($y1) || is_nan($y2)|| is_nan($z1)|| is_nan($z2)){ }
```

and the rest worked. Obviously $y1, $y2 etc. are NAN somehow...
Running XAMP, Win 7 x64, DENWER, PHP v 5.3+